# Getting organization or company details from logged in user on SugarCrm

Tags: api, sugarcrm

I need to get the organization or company details for the logged in user on sugarcrm via api calls.
I searched a lot in sugarcrm api documents but i didn't get any api related to this.

If anyone got this api already let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version? Where are the company details for the user stored? What have you tried?

Comment: @Reisclef i am using v10. i am try to get the company details for the account.Like i need to know the company name for that accouts

Answer (score 0):

The SugarCRM REST v10 API has a series of inbuilt endpoints for obtaining data from the modules.

After you [log in](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Integration/Web_Services/v10/#Authentication), make a GET call to this endpoint based on the ID of the Account:

```
https://{YOURINSTANCENAME}/rest/v10/Accounts/{AccountID}?fields=name
```